# Quarkus resource not found on subdir

Tags: quarkus

i'm facinng an odd problem in a quarkus multiproject root, runner and webapp. The root project have runner and webapp as childs modules and runner have webapp as dependency.
the webapp has:
one index.html inside src/main/resources/META-INF/resources
one ndex.html insede src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/subdir

once compiled from root, running java -jar runner-dev.jar work slikes a charm and i can get access both connecting with chrome using
localhost:8080/
localhost:8080/subdir

but if run java -jar runner.jar i can get access only to the one responding localhost:8080/; connecting to localhost:8080/subdir responds me "Resource not found".

Someone can help me? Is it a bug maybe?

Comment: Had a try with a single simple project and i've the same odd behaviour